# Am I overdoing it with the em dashes here?

Tags: dialogue, formatting

I wrote two versions of the last paragraph for my scene (I included additional context since it also has an em dash). I need help deciding if the second version has too many em dashes and if I should just scrap it:

Gary shoves Jimmy’s hand back. “Shut up, James.” He marches up to Daria until they’re nose to nose, a menacing sneer stretching his face. “Miss goody two shoes here needs to learn she came to the toughest school—”

Daria rolls her eyes.

Version 1:

“—in the country, not some snobby, rich, fancy private school where daddy dearest can save her." He thrusts a finger to her chest, pointing out her Aquaberry vest.

Version 2:

“—in the country, not some snobby”—he thrusts a finger to her chest, pointing out her Aquaberry vest—”rich”—he thrusts his finger again—”fancy”—and again—”private school where daddy dearest can save her.”

I like version 2 more, but I can see how I'm overusing em dashes here or if it's clunky or hard to read.

Comment: I love em dashes, but yeah you are over-doing it.

Comment: cries oh well... thanks tho

Comment: @wetcircuit Would you mind making that an answer?